# Node.js callbacks. Error [TypeError]: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm new to Node.js, Javascript and callbacks.  I have a pretty simple program I'm trying to write and I can't get the callbacks to work.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var keysfetched = false;
var urlsfetched = false;
   
function setKeysfetched(){
    keysfetched = true;
}
    
function setUrlsfetched(){
    urlsfetched = true;
} 
    
//get list of all media in bucket
getKeys(setKeysfetched);
//get a list of all media urls in DB
getUrls(setUrlsfetched);
//check for media in the bucket which is not used
checkKeys();
    
    
function getKeys(callback) {
    
    S3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else{
        var contents = data.Contents;
        contents.forEach(function (content) {
            allKeys.push(content.Key);
        });
    
        if (data.IsTruncated) {
            params.ContinuationToken = data.NextContinuationToken;
            //console.log("get further list...");
            getKeys();
        }
        else{
            console.log("end of loop...");
        }
    }
    });
    callback()
}
```

When I run this I get an error : Error [TypeError]: callback is not a function

If I comment out all of the code inside getKeys(), I don't get the error.

This runs just fine:

```
function getKeys(callback) {

        //Hard work here

        callback()
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `callback` and calling it at the bottom of `getKeys` but inside you are not passing any callback

```
if (data.IsTruncated) {
  params.ContinuationToken = data.NextContinuationToken;
  //console.log("get further list...");
  getKeys();
}
```

So it's trying to call `undefined` which is not a function.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. It took me reading your answer a few times to figure out what you meant. You may want to edit your answer to say "When you call getKeys from inside itself you are not passing in the callback."